# Setting borderwidth of a frame doesn't show a border

Tags: python, tkinter

I follow the tutorials online and the documentations but still can't add a border to a frame. The following is the code I run

```py
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

frame1 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2 )
frame2 = tk.Frame(root, borderwidth=2 )
frame1.grid(row = 0)
frame2.grid(row = 1)

tk.Label(frame1, text = 'frame1').grid(row = 0)
tk.Label(frame2, text = 'frame2').grid(row = 0)

root.mainloop()
```

And this is the result I got. What's the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `relief` option to one of "raised", "sunken", "ridge", or "groove". On your system it appears the default is "flat". The final option is "solid".

[image: examples of tkinter borders]